# Why can not idea2022 run python program?

Tags: intellij-idea

I run a python program in idea2022.2, but an error appears, my environment is python3, jdk8, global enviroonment is python3. Does idea not support jdk8?

The burst error prompt is as follows:

```
'java.util.function.Function com.intellij.execution.target.value.TargetEnvironmentFunctions.getTargetEnvironmentValueForLocalPath(com.intellij.execution.target.TargetEnvironmentRequest, java.nio.file.Path)'
```

Answer (score 3):

Workaround - disable Help | Find Action | Registry | python.use.targets.api.

Thanks to Pavel Karateev. Source:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56176/Cannot-open-project-when-Python-plugin-is-enabled-in-202222#focus=Comments-27-6448075.0-0

Comment: Works. Can work with Python again.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Settings/Preferences -> Plugins -> Installed
2. Uninstall Python plugin
3. Restart IDEA
4. Install Python plugin back

That should resolve the problem.

Comment: This is one didn't work for me, but disabling python.use.targets.api helped. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

JetBrains at their best again.

Here is a solution for you:

1. Go there: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/631-python/versions
2. Download .zip of Python 222.4167.29 (Date Sep 14, 2022).
3. Press Shift 2 times, type "Plugins" and press "Enter".
4. Click the cog icon and then click "Install Plugin from Disk".
5. Select the plugin archive file (.zip) and click OK.
6. Click OK to apply the changes and restart your IDE if prompted.